# using intervals in a column to populate values for another column

Tags: r, group-by, data-cleaning, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
dataframe <- data.frame(Condition = rep(c(1,2,3), each = 5, times = 2),
                        Time = sort(sample(1:60, 30)))
     Condition Time
1          1    1
2          1    3
3          1    4
4          1    7
5          1    9
6          2   11
7          2   12
8          2   14
9          2   16
10         2   18
11         3   19
12         3   24
13         3   25
14         3   28
15         3   30
16         1   31
17         1   34
18         1   35
19         1   38
20         1   39
21         2   40
22         2   42
23         2   44
24         2   47
25         2   48
26         3   49
27         3   54
28         3   55
29         3   57
30         3   59
```

I want to divide the total length of `Time` (i.e., max(Time) - min(Time)) per `Condition` by a constant 'x' (e.g., 3). Then I want to use that quotient to add a new variable `Trial` such that my dataframe looks like this:

```
     Condition Time Trial
1          1    1     A
2          1    3     A
3          1    4     B
4          1    7     C
5          1    9     C
6          2   11     A
7          2   12     A
8          2   14     B
9          2   16     C
10         2   18     C
... and so on
```

As you can see, for Condition 1, Trial is populated with unique identifying values (e.g., A, B, C) every 2.67 seconds = 8 (total time) / 3. For Condition 2, Trial is populated every 2.33 seconds = 7 (total time) /3.

I am not getting what I want with my current code:

```
dataframe %>%
  group_by(Condition) %>%
  mutate(Trial = LETTERS[cut(Time, 3, labels = F)])

# Groups:   Condition [3]
   Condition  Time Trial
       <dbl> <int> <chr>
 1         1     1 A    
 2         1     3 A    
 3         1     4 A    
 4         1     7 A    
 5         1     9 A    
 6         2    11 A    
 7         2    12 A    
 8         2    14 A    
 9         2    16 A    
10         2    18 A    
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need `dataframe %>% group_by(Condition) %>% mutate(Trial = LETTERS[cut(Time, diff(range(Time))/3, labels = FALSE)])`

Comment: Is your expected output correct?  Based on the calculation, 16 should be 'B'

Comment: It is unclear how you are getting 2.67 and 2.33 when your calculation showed is `(max(Time) - min(Time)) /3`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I created the table by hand to demonstrate my issue. Going down from the first row, for Condition 1, max(Time) = 9 and min(Time) = 1. Thus total time = 8, and 8/3 = 2.67. Same with Condition 2 where total time is 7.

Comment: @ktiu actually answered my question in another thread. I will close this post.

Comment: I get different values for 1, i.e. 1 and 31 for min/max

Comment: Please don't close the post as I showed a different way

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The question is still confusing because indeed the max in condition 1 is 31, not 9. You need to clarify what your conditions are in your actual data. Presumably if you grouped by the true groups, your code would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the `diff`rence of `range` (returns `min/max` as a `vector`) and divide by the constant passed into i.e. 3 as the `breaks` in `cut`).  Then, use integer index (`labels = FALSE`) to get the corresponding LETTER from the `LETTERS` builtin R constant

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe %>% 
    group_by(Condition) %>%
    mutate(Trial = LETTERS[cut(Time, diff(range(Time))/3,
        labels = FALSE)])
```

---

If the grouping should be based on adjacent values in 'Condition', use `rleid` from `data.table` on the 'Condition' column to create the grouping, and apply the same code as above

```
library(data.table)
dataframe %>%
    group_by(grp = rleid(Condition)) %>%
     mutate(Trial = LETTERS[cut(Time, diff(range(Time))/3,
        labels = FALSE)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner using my `santoku` package. The `rleid` line is the same as mentioned in @akrun's solution.

```r
    dataframe %<>% 
         group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(Condition)) %>% 
         mutate(
           Trial = chop_evenly(Time, intervals = 3, labels = lbl_seq("A"))
         )
```